# C# shortcut for storing long types?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary that is of type:

```
Dictionary<(string, string), List<(decimal amount, decimal price, long timestampUnixEpoch)>>
```

Eg:

```
Dictionary<(string, string), List<(decimal amount, decimal price, long timestampUnixEpoch)>> someDict;
```

I will be doing some unboxing and boxing of objects for this type, and thus need to cast it. I find that simply casting it as such takes up too much room per lline, eg:

```
(Dictionary<(string, string), List<(decimal amount, decimal price, long timestampUnixEpoch)>>) boxedObject //unbox cast
```

Can I possibly reference the type using a shorter variable? I tried using the Type type but I'm not sure if this can be used for that. Any suggestions for this and any other types that are long?

Comment: This is a good sign that you should stop using tuples, and create your own structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [*using alias directive*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

```
using MyDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<(string, string), System.Collections.Generic.List<(decimal amount, decimal price, long timestampUnixEpoch)>>;
```

Add this line at the top and you can use `MyDict` as the type name instead.

But really, this is a sign that you are abusing tuples. You should create your own structs, really:

```
// give these structs better names if you can
struct StringPair {
    public string Item1 { get; }
    public string Item2 { get; }

    public StringPair(string item1, string item2) {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var pair = (StringPair)obj;
        return Item1 == pair.Item1 && Item2 == pair.Item2;
    }

    // remember to implement Equals and GetHashCode!
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return HashCode.Combine(Item1, Item2);
    }

}

struct Item {
    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
    public long TimestampUnixEpoch { get; }

    public Item(decimal amount, decimal price, long timestampUnixEpoch) {
        Amount = amount;
        Price = price;
        TimestampUnixEpoch = timestampUnixEpoch;
    }
}
```

And then you can use `Dictionary<StringPair, List<Item>>` instead.